# movie formats missing

Tags: rendering

I am using

Blender 2.83.3

```
    build date: 2020-07-22

    build time: 06:01:36

    build commit date: 2020-07-22

    build commit time: 06:01

    build hash: 353e5bd7493e

    build platform: Linux

    build type: Release
```

In "video editing" the output property of the current scene looks like this
[image]
shows only three movie formats. Formats that can also store audio are missing.

Comment: What formats did you expect or require? This is the standard, there are no formats missing. Audio formats can be selected during a mixdown.

Comment: If you choose FFmpeg video you can then specify the container and the codec. Did you tried?

Comment: I had seen tutorials with a longer list of movie formats, but now I notice that this was for earlier Blender versions, 2.7.6 or so.

Comment: Thanks! Chosing  FFmpeg I could get it working in the end.